# Installation of obs failed

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 22.04

I am using the linux distro 22.04.2.
I used the installation instructions from the obs site. When I attempted to install the repository, I got a notice that some packages were missing so older ones were used. Then, when I attempted to install obs, when I gave the command to install I received the following error:

> Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend.
> It is held by process 4655 (unattended-upgr)

I am new to linux, but could not find anything with this process or error on this site.

Comment: You're likely using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (you mention "*linux distro is 22.04.2*" which is vague; Linux is a kernel & exists in Ubuntu, many other *distros* and even Android on phones/tablets/tvs etc).  If you're using Ubuntu 22.04.2 still you're well behind on applying security fixes; as a fully updated Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system will report itself currently as 22.04.3, with 22.04.4 updates installing now (eg. 6.5 kernel if using HWE stack) but it doesn't change to report itself as 22.04.4 until **after** all upgrades are applied.  If your system reports as 22.04.2 you're near six months behind..

Comment: You are likely using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS if you look (`lsb_release -a` for example will show some details about your system) and 22.04.2 was your install media maybe? but you also mention "*some packages were missing so older ones were used*" which would fit your system being outdated & need to apply security fixes asap if you use your system online.  We're limited to details you provide; but I'll suggest running `sudo apt update` to update your software lists (*so your machine knows what is available*) then applying upgrades with `sudo apt upgrade` if there are no warnings/errors to first cmd

Comment: You don't need to use the obs site. The Ubuntu repositories have a version of obs that is tested to work with your OS. Just do `sudo apt install obs-studio`

Comment: plus *snap* package option(s) too, eg. `obs-studio                   30.0.0                   snapcrafters✪               -        Free and open source software for live streaming and screen recording`